# ASNetworkImageNode gif not loading

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I am creating custom node to show gif file with play and pause button. 
Following is my code.

```swift
import Foundation
import AsyncDisplayKit

class GifNode: ASCellNode {
    var gifImageNode:ASNetworkImageNode = {
        let node = ASNetworkImageNode()
        node.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        node.shouldRenderProgressImages = true
        return node
    }()
    var playImage: ASImageNode = {
        let node = ASImageNode()
        node.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        node.style.height = ASDimensionMakeWithPoints(30)
        node.style.height = ASDimensionMakeWithPoints(30)
        node.backgroundColor = .gray
        node.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "play")
        return node
    }()

    init(model:GifContent)
    {
        super.init()

        self.automaticallyManagesSubnodes = true

        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let height = (width * model.height) / model.width

        gifImageNode.url =  URL(string: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/07/44/38/074438e7c75034df2dcf37ba1057803e.gif")
        gifImageNode.style.width = ASDimensionMake(width)
        gifImageNode.style.height = ASDimensionMake(height)

        gifImageNode.animatedImagePaused = true

        gifImageNode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleGifPlay), forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func toggleGifPlay()
    {
        self.gifImageNode.animatedImagePaused = !self.gifImageNode.animatedImagePaused
        self.playImage.isHidden = !self.gifImageNode.animatedImagePaused
    }

    override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
        let playButtonCenterSpec = ASCenterLayoutSpec(centeringOptions: .XY, sizingOptions: .minimumXY, child: self.playImage)
        return ASOverlayLayoutSpec(child: gifImageNode, overlay: playButtonCenterSpec)
    }
}
```

When I try to use gif node in another ASCellNode it does not render. I can see play button but not the actual gif file. If I try to load jpeg with same control, it works fine. Also it works fine, if I try to load gif directly and not using above class.

Not sure if I am missing anything.

Comment: Do you use the same URL for another Node? Mb it's just cashed?

Comment: I tried same as well as different url.

Comment: Can you provide simple app example for play with it?

Comment: I have created git repository [AsyncDisplayKitGifIssue](https://github.com/hmane/AsyncDisplayKitGifIssue). There are 2 functions in MyNode.swift. You can toggle to see the result.

Comment: I test your app, but `gifImageNode.animatedImagePaused = true` is disabled by default ur animation, what do you want? Can you skype to me: bimawa

Comment: http://take.ms/JeD4v

Comment: so stupid. Didnt realize that animatedImagePaused was causing this issue. Thanks again @Bimawa

Comment: No problem, my friend. I'll try to add an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your app, but `gifImageNode.animatedImagePaused = true` is disabled by default ur animation.